# NullReferenceException when polling Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client for builds

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to implement a simple polling service that queries our TFS instance for build results (eventually this will be shown on a build monitor in the office). Following the examples [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples), I've come up with the following attempt:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection");
var connection = new VssConnection(uri, new VssClientCredentials());
var client = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

var builds = await client.GetBuildsAsync(
    project: "OurProject",
    maxBuildsPerDefinition: 1,
    type: DefinitionType.Build);
```

but the last statement throws a `NullReferenceException` somewhere deep in the client library (full stack trace at the bottom).

I've tried the following, and it works, but of course it doesn't get me the information I'm looking for :)

```
var client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var workItems = await client.GetWorkItemsAsync(ids: new List<int> { 7000, 7005});
```

**Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about how to query for builds? How do I avoid this exception?**

---

## Update: It's not just me!

I just discovered that this error isn't generated (only) on the client side; it's on the server side (too)! A `GET` request to the following url:

```
http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultCollection/OurProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1&type=build
```

yields a `500 Internal Server Error` response with the following content:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "typeName": "System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
  "typeKey": "NullReferenceException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 0
}
```

Given this, how should I troubleshoot? What should I ask/tell the ops people who are running our TFS server? What are we looking for?

---

Stack trace for the (client-side) exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__47`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync>d__53`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__52`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Work() in c:\users\tly01\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 32
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\tly01\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 20
```

Comment: Are you querying for XAML builds or task-based builds?

Comment: @DanielMann: Task-based (the other member of the enum I pass is `DefinitionType.Xaml`).

Comment: @DanielMann: I just discovered that this error is caused on the server side (or, at least there too...). Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Short answer, RTFM :)

It turns out that the `maxBuildsPerDefinition` parameter is only valid if `definitions` is also specified. If only the former is given, the server returns 500.

(You could argue that 401 Bad Request would have been a better response, but at least now I know what to do about it.)

My workaround was to do the filtering on the client side instead; I get all builds of all projects, then group by definition and select the latest one:

```
var builds = await client
    .GetBuildsAsync(
        project: "OurProject",
        type: DefinitionType.Build).Result
    .GroupBy(build => build.Definition.Id)
    .Select(g => g
        .OrderByDescending(build.FinishTime ?? build.StartTime ?? DateTime.MinValue)
        .First());
```